# Angular 2 and Redux store injection

Tags: angular, redux

I have just started learning Angular2 and Redux. From what I understood, the the store keeps the global state of the app and will be injected as a dependency to the components who need to communicate with it.

I'm not comfortable with the idea of injecting the store directly into the components and I want to create a service layer that will effectively communicate with the store and the components will communicate with that service layer and not the store directly. I wonder if doing that is contradictory to the principles of Redux ?

Comment: your understanding is correct. Read more about redux from [**here**](https://redux.js.org/) and you can set up the basic store using `ngrx-store` as said in this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)